# How to work pdf file at step by step slides in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I added a next button in my html code which will redirect me to my the same views.py function as shown above and t shall increment by 5 thus showing me my next 5 slides. However this seems not to .

Comment: do you have more information, what does your code look like?

Comment: I want  to create slideshare frame using django. please help me.